# Setting state from another component react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

There a two components one is `<Form />` and other is `<LoginForm />`. 
`<LoginForm />` looks like

```
const LoginForm = () => {
   return (
      <Form
         inputs={[
             //some objects here               
         ]}
         onSubmit={(data, setError) => {
             setError('some error')
         }}
      />
   );
};
```

The `<Form />` component looks like.

```
const Form = ({onSumbit, inputs}) => {
   const [error, setError] = useState(''); 
   return (
      <>
         {error ? <div>{error}</div> : null}
         {//rendering inputs here}
         <button onClick={() => onSubmit('some data which is not relative to problem', setError)}>
      </>
    )
}
```

Now when the button is clicked on `onSubmit()` should run. And it should call `setError` which should show some error but its not showing any error. Its also not showing any kind of error.

**Note:** This is only the relevant part of code. Code is actually large. But I am sure that only this part have some basic flaw.

Comment: Solved: was a typo `onSumbit` vs `onSubmit`

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you declared `onSumbit` and sometimes `onSubmit`, you need to be consistent:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={(data, setter) => {
        setter('some error');
      }}
    />
  );
};

const Form = ({ onSubmit, inputs }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  return (
    <>
      {error ? <div>{error}</div> : null}
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          onSubmit('some data which is not relative to problem', setError);
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit sharp-cartwright-lgc62]

Answer (score -1):

You had typos and syntax errors previously so this couldn't have worked for you anyway.

This seems to do what you meant.

```js
const Form = ({ onSubmit, inputs }) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      {error ? <div>{error}</div> : null}
      {// rendering inputs here
      }
      <button onClick={() => onSubmit('data', setError)} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: I want to  `setError()` from the parent Component `<LoginForm />`

Comment: Edited to fit your usecase after you'd also edited your original post. Also, why are you downvoting all answers?

Comment: First thanks for giving time to question. Second the problem was something which i just fixed. And third how can you say I am downvoting answers?

Answer (score -1):

Here is my code. It works fine. Maybe there is some typo in your code.

```js
const Form = ({onSubmit, inputs}) => {
  const [error, setError] = useState(''); 
  return (
    <>
        {error ? <div>{error}</div> : null}
        <button onClick={() => onSubmit('some data which is not relative to problem', setError)}>
          Hi
        </button>
    </>
  )
}

const LoginForm = () => {
  return (
     <Form
        inputs={[
            //some objects here               
        ]}
        onSubmit={(data, setError) => {
            setError('some error')
        }}
     />
  );
};
```

Comment: I have fixed the issue. It was about async nature of data. You are right the given code should work fine.

Comment: Yeah its my mistake sorry for that. But I would say your answer doesn't make any sense. There is nothing to solve problem or even something which could show that the code is working fine. a